# Sending session specific messages with socket.io and sails.js

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I'm trying to implement a private chat functionality, using sails.js framework, and i'm having some troubles when trying so send a message to a particular user.

Currently, I've achieved private communication by sending the messages to a particular socket.id, using the socket.io's `.socket(socket.id).emit(event,message)`, but the problem with that approach is that every time the user opens a new tab, a new socket.id is generated, for that new connection.

And my question is: does sails.js facilitates a way of emitting events (using socket.io) to an specific user *session* instead of a bunch of socket ids? is it possible with these technologies?

So I can send the event only once, and making sure it is received in all the tabs where the chat app is currently open.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sails augments all of its models with some useful pubsub methods.  Whenever you find a model via a socket request (e.g. `socket.get('/user/123')` ) the requesting socket is automatically subscribed to all messages about that model.  You can then call `User.message(123, data)` to send a message to all of the connected sockets for that user.

Docs for the pubsub methods are [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets).