# Emitting a message in sails v0.11 (client-side)

Tags: sockets, socket.io, sails.js

I'm having some issues with the newest version of sails.js (0.11.0).  It stated in github that plain socket.io code will be accepted and ran in sails.js; however, I am simply trying to emit a message from a client when they click on something like so:

```
$('#myBtn').on('click', function(){
     io.socket.emit('message', {  
         message: {
             subject: subject
         },
         sender: id
     });  

});
```

I end up getting an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on the line of `io.socket.emit()` aka `emit` is not a function of io.socket.

Here are some references that I have looked at:

- https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2397
- http://www.tysoncadenhead.com/blog/getting-started-with-socket-io#.VQCFjvnF9tU

I have a feeling with the updated version of sails, instead of emitting a message I should be doing something along the lines of:

```
io.socket.post('/user/message', data, function(data, jwres) {

});
```

Something concerns me with the following answer here:

- [Sending session specific messages with socket.io and sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167451/sending-session-specific-messages-with-socket-io-and-sails-js)

It states "class rooms" are being deprecated along with `publishCreate`, `publishDestroy`, `introduce`, and `obituary`.

So do I follow a Pub/Sub paradigm, re-write my more "socket-io-ish" code to utilize sails Blueprints & Pub/Sub, or continue in my socket-io fashion?

Is there another way of emitting a message from client using sails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in that the recommended way of communicating with the server via sockets is to use the RESTful [socket client methods](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.io.js).  The benefit is that you can use the regular Sails routing and controller/action architecture for socket communication instead of having to support a whole other layer of subscription and event-handling on the backend.  This is one of the main reasons why @mikermcneil originally created Sails.  Two things to note:

1. You can use [`req.isSocket`](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/req/req.isSocket.html) in your controller action to determine whether the request is coming from a socket, and
2. You can get the raw, underlying socket.io instance on the client with `io.socket._raw`, which will have the `emit` method.  But again, this is not the recommended practice.